# I am trying to parse JSON from the Swift subreddit. Why am I having issues?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I am wondering why I am getting keyNotFound when parsing JSON using Decodable.

I need to parse the JSON from https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/.json
I need the "selftext" fields for a description as well as the "url" for the image. They are nested differently.

So far, here is my Reddit model:

```
import Foundation

struct Model : Decodable {
    let data: ListingData
}

struct ListingData: Decodable {
    let children: [Child]
}

struct Child: Decodable {
    let data: ChildData
}

struct ChildData : Decodable {
    let selftext: String
    let preview: ImageURL
}

struct ImageURL: Decodable {
    let url: URL
}
```

Here is my NetworkingService:

```
import Foundation

class NetworkingService {

    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    private init() {}

    let session = URLSession.shared

    func getReddits(success successBlock: @escaping (ChildData) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/.json") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        session.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard self != nil else { return }

            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                let model = try decoder.decode(ChildData.self, from: data!)
                successBlock(model)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

My HomeViewController with collectionView looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private var reddits: [ChildData] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "RedditsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "RedditsCollectionViewCell")

        NetworkingService.shared.getReddits { [weak self] (response) in
            self?.reddits = [response]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    //Number of views
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reddits.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let redditCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RedditCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? RedditCollectionViewCell {

                print("collection1 \(redditCell.isAnimated)")
                redditCell.updateCell(with: reddits[indexPath.row])

            return redditCell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {
    func reloadData(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion() }
    }
}
```

Finally, my Cell looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class RedditCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var redditImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redditTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var viewCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func updateCell(with reddit: ChildData) {
    }
}

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImage(from url: URL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think your model will work? It doesn't match the JSON you get at all.

Comment: And please remove the unrelated code.

Comment: Sorry!! I had the wrong URL in the code.

Comment: Looks like `ImageURL` does not represent the JSON. `preview` is an object with a property named `images`, which is an array of some other object type, which itself has objects/arrays for its `source`, `resolutions`, and `variants` fields. And it looks like `source` has a `url` field – maybe that's the URL you are trying to get?

Comment: The URL that you'r using `https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/.json` is not working.

Comment: @PGDev I get a postman response.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to start from your root struct, `Model` when decoding

```
let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data!)
```

then your struct declaration was wrong since the url part was nested further down so I need to add some structs and also `preview` seems to not always be present so I made that property optional

```
struct ChildData : Decodable {
   let selftext: String
   let preview: Images?
}

struct Images : Decodable {
    let images: [Source]
}

struct Source : Decodable {
    let source: ImageURL
}
struct ImageURL: Decodable {
    let url: URL
}
```

My simple print to verify the code

```
let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data!)
for child in model.data.children {
    if let image = child.data.preview?.images.first {
        print(image.source.url)
    }
}
```